# How to user .trigger() inside .dblclick() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, eventtrigger

I am trying to perform a trigger click of the button on the double click of the list element.
I have 2 elements. One is a button and the second is a UL list element.

**Here is the HTML button and List code.**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" id="show_comment_modal" data-target="#showCommentModal">  Show Comment </button>

<ul>
    <li id="category_list_1">Coffee</li>
    <li id="category_list_2">Tea</li>
    <li id="category_list_3">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

**Here is the Jquery code:**

```
    $( "#category_list_1" ).dblclick(function() {
        $( "#show_comment_modal" ).trigger( "click" );
    });
```

I did not get any error in console.
Did this even possible?

Comment: Try `$("#show_comment_modal")[0].click()` to invoke the core-js click handler

Comment: As [shown here](https://jsfiddle.net/1b4yojxz/) there's nothing wrong with your code to *trigger* the click event, but it maybe that what it's doing is not triggered on a "click".

Comment: If you're trying to show the modal when `#category_list_1` is double-clicked it would be far better to invoke the method which displays the modal directly, rather than creating a fake user event in the DOM. For example, jQueryUI has the [`show()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open) method, but I'm sure whichever library you're using will have similar functionality.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i get your point sir, but here I have some more operations, some values to be passed and set in the modal before opening it. so on the trigger, I was sending that values which get from that connected button, but I got your comment that I needed to make a Clear operation in terms of using this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#show_comment_modal').click(function() {
  alert('button click');
});

$('.category').dblclick(function() {
  $('#show_comment_modal').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="show_comment_modal">  Show Comment </button>

<ul>
    <li class="category" id="category_list_1">Coffee</li>
    <li class="category" id="category_list_2">Tea</li>
    <li class="category" id="category_list_3">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Here you have a code snippet with an example

Comment: thanks for the answer, I see you have added click event instead of trigger click, is any specific issue with `trigger` event,  as I have 2 different buttons so 1 is opening the modal on dubble click and second one is do actually done other task, so that's why I was looking for `trigger` event, did this above work with 2 buttons?

Comment: There is no real difference between trigger and click in this case. The jquery code of click calls trigger. Trigger is more efficient, I have added click instead trigger because I'm used to click.